# Heat equation and boundary conditions

Tags: heat-equation

I am reading about the one dimensional heat equation and boundary conditions. This is what the author writes about the left hand end of the rod:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the slope must be positive at $x=0$? If the rod is hotter shouldn't it loose temperature, i.e. negative slope?

Answer (score 1):

The slope in the $t$ direction *is* negative because the temp is dropping over time.  But in the $x$ direction, the change in heat is positive, because things are cooler to the left.

Comment: Then the question is: why is $u_x (L, t) \le 0$ (understood as directional derivative at $x=L$ from the left), given that $x=L$ is the maximum?

Comment: This is at the right end of the rod, and there, things are cooler to the right.  When $t=0$, the graph of the temperature distribution is some sort of discontinuous function where there's a step up at $x=0$ and a step down at $x=L$.  A short time later, these steps are smoothed over, but there's still a sharp slope up at the left and a sharp slope down at the right.

Comment: So you are saying that the derivative that I am talking about is the one from the right (where there is no rod), not from the left? If so, then the text is a bit idiotic (a statement supported by the abundance of colours and gloss in that book). Unfortunately, I believe that formulations like this are to be expected from authors whose books reach the 10th edition...

Comment: The derivative at $x=0$ is at the left.  The derivative at $x=L$ is at the right. There is no rod to the left of $x=0$ or to the right of $x=L$, but there is "surrounding medium", so the heat has a place to go.  (Yeah, non-narcissistic textbook authors are rare.)

Comment: I am confused. Is it right or wrong? I still dont get it

Comment: I think it's right.  Perhaps if you draw a picture of the initial temperature, including the surrounding medium, and then imagine the temp one second later, you'll see the derivatives.